How can I create a scope isolated from parents and globals other than using the `with` statement over a Proxy?
I'm trying to reset the scope, as in hide all variables except a select few, in JavaScript. I know I can use the with keyword and a proxy, but it is deprecated and not allowed in strict mode. As far as I know, there are no other ways to hide all variables.
Here is what I can do with with:
// allow access to console
const target = { console };
// no unscopable variables
target[Symbol.unscopables] = new Proxy({}, { get() { return false; } })

const handler = {
    // always intercept variable references
    has(..._) { return true; },
    
    get(target, prop, receiver) {
        if (!(prop in target)) {
            let error;
            try {
                // throw usual TypeError
                error = new TypeError(`${prop} is not defined`);
            } catch(_) {
                // in case `prop` can't be converted to a string
                error = new TypeError("a variable is not defined");
            }
            throw error;
        }
        // default getter
        return Reflect.get(...arguments);
    }

    // default setter
}

const proxy = new Proxy(target, handler);
with(proxy) {
   console.log("Hello, World!"); // "Hello, World!"
   console.log(window); // TypeError: window is not defined
}


with is for adding to the scope chain (the intent was to make it more convenient to access properties, by not having to write the container all the time), not for hiding scope. This is a perverse use of it. It wasn't the intent, and I don't think a new way is provided to do it.

What is the real problem you're trying to solve by clearing the scope? In modern JavaScript, top-level variables defined in modules are not put into the global scope.

You might be looking for a shadow realm or compartment. But until those proposals are implemented, with+proxy is probably the way to go. Strict mode should not be an issue - presumably you are using eval/new Function anyway?

(_=>0).constructor("return this")() will let “sandboxed” code access globals anyway. Or it could mutate prototypes of intrinsics with __proto__…
